# Canvas.rotate call is causing drawn items to disappear?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am trying to rotate a bitmap when drawing it to a canvas. The problem is that when I call canvas.rotate(90) anything that is drawn after that does not actually get drawn. Running the following code will draw nothing to the screen when I have the rotate call in there. If I take out the rotate call it shows up fine. Why would the rotate call stop the bitmap from showing up on the canvas?

```
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(90);
        canvas.drawBitmap(leaves, null, leafRect, bitmapPaint);
        canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, rotate() will rotate the canvas from the exact center. You probably want to rotate from the center of your bitmap.

```
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(90, leafRect.x + (leafRect.width / 2), leafRect.y + (leafRect.height / 2));
    canvas.drawBitmap(leaves, null, leafRect, bitmapPaint);
    canvas.restore();
```

More info at the docs [rotate(angle, x, y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29)